# Why do you access Symbol.iterator via brackets?

Tags: javascript, arrays, iterator, symbols

If I created an array, for instance, `var array=[1,2,3,4];` to return an iterator I would do `var iterator = array[Symbol.iterator]();` I don't understand why you access the Symbol.iterator property through brackets? Why isn't it just `array.Symbol.iterator`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no property on an array called `Symbol` (unless you put one there). Instead you are looking up the values whose key is the symbol primitive that `Symbol.iterator` points to. `Symbol.iterator` returns a symbol and you use that symbol as the lookup key. It's a little like looking up a property with a variable:

```js
let a = [1, 2, 3]
a.someProp = "hello"

let key = "someProp"

// this doesn't work for the same reason s.Symbol.iterator doesn't:
// a.key

// but this does:
console.log(a[key])

// So with a Symbol:

let k = Symbol.iterator
console.log(typeof k)
// k is now a reference to the symbol that is the key
// you can use that to returns the iterator function
console.log(a[k])    // <-- that returns your iterator function
console.log([...a[k]()])

// equivalent to:
console.log([...a[Symbol.iterator]()])
```

Answer (score 2):

Because that's how the iterable protocol works. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols):

> The iterable protocol allows JavaScript objects to define or customize their iteration behavior, such as what values are looped over in a for..of construct. Some built-in types are built-in iterables with a default iteration behavior, such as Array or Map, while other types (such as Object) are not.
>
> In order to be iterable, an object must implement the @@iterator method, meaning that the object (or one of the objects up its prototype chain) must have a property with a @@iterator key which is available via constant Symbol.iterator:

The interpreter needs a way to determine whether a *generic* object is iterable. While it could have been specified that each iterable object has a string `iterator` property that, when called, returns an iterator for that object, that might be a problem for (pre-iterator) objects that may have happened to have the `iterator` property but don't conform to the actual specification iterator protocol.

Requiring that the iterator property is accessed via a (unique, iterator-specific) `Symbol` ensures that no such problematic collisions can take place.

(as a side note: `array.Symbol.iterator` would require `Symbol` to be a property of `array`, which wouldn't make much sense - `Symbol` is a *global object*)

Answer (score 1):

`array.Symbol.iterator` says "access the `Symbol` member of the `array` variable, and then access that value's `iterator` member" however that will return the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'iterator' of undefined` because the array doesn't have a member called `Symbol` and so it returns `undefined` and `undefined` doesn't have an `iterator` member.

The dot `.` operator in JS is left-associative so it's evaluated from left-to-right. You need to use brackets to clarify what you want, and what you want is to access the `iterator` of `Symbol` and then use that value to access a member of the `array` variable.

To use a math analogy, the difference between `array.Symbol.iterator` and `array[Symbol.iterator]` is like the difference between `6 / 0 + 2` (undefined, can't divide by 0) and `6 / (0 + 2)` (= 3, valid operation!).